# Cleanest way to handle browser back button

Tags: javascript, html

As far as my [Google Seaches](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/) . I found following `script` that will let me handle `back button` in most of the browsers but **not all**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
    function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
</script>

<body onload="noBack();"
    onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">
</body>
```

Is there any generic solution for all the browser to handle this issue? I heard of something like setting timeout will do but dont' know how to use it with above script.

### **Why I need to handle it**

I have a product cart page where user can `add/delete/edit` products in a cart. If user select any of the product he gets redirected to product info page.

On product cart page(`add/delete/edit`) if user deletes particulate product and presses the back button I want him to stay on current page as product has been removed from the cart.But with browser cache user still get's redirected to product info page which is what the bug in my case.

### Edit:

All three operations(`add/edit/delete`) are `asych AJAX` call's.But User has facility to revisit his cart from any page.

Lets say user

1. `selects` product from `product cart` page.
2. gets `redirected` to `product details` page
3. Click on `product cart` link takes to product cart again
4. `deletes` the product from cart
5. presses `back button`

Here is what the real issue starts.

Comment: By handle the back button - I assume you mean 'disable'.  Why would you want to do this? Can you explain what you are trying to archive by disabling the expected behaviour and annoying users?

Comment: why do you want the user to stay on the current page, when hitting the back button is the user's legitimate indicator that *they* want to go to the previous page? Why are you trying to break their browser UX? Just make your add/delete/edit actions async and update the page they're on without them needing to reload the page. Use modern web features.

Comment: No offense, but this type of desired behavior is normally caused by bad design.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Although  `user's legitimate ` It should not happen as delete dont make any sense in this case.I may have a bad design.But then how can I make it good to support in all the browsers?

Comment: make your edit operations in-page, so that a user clicking your "delete" button updates the page using an async ajax operation. That way there is no page to "go back to". Hence the comment "use modern web features". Don't go to a new page every time your users do an add/edit/delete. Stay on the same page and update the HTML based on your ajax call results

Answer (score 0):

you need to define some logic for doing such thing, for example if I go from pag1 to page2 , then by your code I can't back to page1 using back button but there are two problems with your solution:

1. user can disable javascript
2. user can copy page1 url into address bar.

if you are trying to control some authentication or login access or anything like this you must use sessions. by the way you must say why do you want to do this, then there might be server side solution for it (much more treatable than js)